# ¿Por qué este código agrega un símbolo extraño al final de mi string?

Tags: c

Estaba realizando unas pruebas con un juez online, mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
int i;
char mystring[100];

scanf("%s",mystring);

char newString[strlen(mystring)];

for(i=0;i<strlen(mystring);i++){
    if(mystring[i]==toupper(mystring[i])){
        newString[i] = tolower(mystring[i]);
    }else{
        newString[i] = toupper(mystring[i]);
    }
}
printf("%s",newString);
}
```

El código cambia los caracteres en mayúscula a minúscula y las minúsculas en mayúsculas, el problema es que al compilar me arroja que agrega una letra extraña al final del string:

Entrada:

> RrHRxcUsSrvSnTyolvsxHoGyzwBMzuLCUjcSeWmBAhodtEkgZjDkFjaXXAvjTvRfHuHGtopoxaeONzFFurfNlRdAvRYlnlfdIMsI

Salida esperada:

> rRhrXCuSsRVsNtYOLVSXhOgYZWbmZUlcuJCsEwMbaHODTeKGzJdKfJAxxaVJtVrFhUhgTOPOXAEonZffURFnLrDaVryLNLFDimSi

Mi salida:

> rRhrXCuSsRVsNtYOLVSXhOgYZWbmZUlcuJCsEwMbaHODTeKGzJdKfJAxxaVJtVrFhUhgTOPOXAEonZffURFnLrDaVryLNLFDimSiÿ

Como pueden ver realiza su trabajo a la perfección excepto por que produce una "ÿ", ¿de dónde sale esto?

Al compilarlo desde mi propio PC no veo este símbolo pero esto se puede deber a que no está en el alfabeto de mi PC o el IDE simplemente no lo soporta.

Puedo arreglar esto simplemente eliminando el caracter del array ya que siempre pasa pero aun así esto no debería ocurrir.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que la **cadena de caracteres**, es decir, el `string` ingresado por teclado ocupa 101 caracteres, pero el array solo soporta 100. En el lenguaje **C**, todos los strings tienen 1 caracter más al final, se llama **barra cero** `\0`, esto significa que en hexadecimal es `\x00`, por eso ocupa 101 aunque sea de 100.

Por ejemplo, para escribir `Hola`, la cadena ocupa 5 caracteres, `Hola\0`.

Dejo el ejemplo [aquí](http://cpp.sh/4ujq).

La cadena produce el siguiente error:

`char mystring[100]={"RrHRxcUsSrvSnTyolvsxHoGyzwBMzuLCUjcSeWmBAhodtEkgZjDkFjaXXAvjTvRfHuHGtopoxaeONzFFurfNlRdAvRYlnlfdIMsI"};`

> In function 'int main()':
>
> 8:127: error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]

**Datos adicionales:** ¿Cómo solucionar este problema?

1. Aumentar la longitud a 101 caracteres
2. Poner valor `0` (cero) en la última posición.

La función `printf` está programada para no mostrar el `\0`, y justo por ese motivo se debe ingresar `\0` al final de cada string. En realidad lo que intenta mostrar esa función es el contenido de un puntero a `char`, ya que los `strings` no existen en **C**, pero sí en **C++**.

Hacer una función propia para mostrarlos no está mal, pero el resultado sería el mismo, no afectaría al rendimiento tampoco. También se podría hacer una función que agregue el `\0` automáticamente, para que quede más limpio el código.

Comment: Sugerencia podrías agregar el termino en inglés para cadena , es decir string, algo así como "cadena (string)". Tal vez por completitud debería decir el término completo, es decir cadena de caracteres.

Comment: @ElAsiduo Cambiado. Es cierto, es la costumbre, a medida que uno adquiere experiencia tiene que simplificar los términos, por eso omití la frase completa.

Comment: Pero entonteces ¿no puedo imprimir directamente el string por que siempre agregara al final ese carácter extraño? ya que los jueces online son 100% estrictos con las salidas. Lo solucione imprimiendo char por char el string.

Comment: @CristoferFuentes Ahí agregué unos _datos adicionales_ para responder a eso.

Comment: @ArtEze "*justo por ese motivo se debe ingresar `\0` al final de cada string*" estoy casi seguro que el `scanf` ya agrega el caracter nulo al final de la cadena al leer en el búfer.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Así es, si uno pega la cadena directamente al código sin usar `scanf`, entonces es necesario, tal como lo hice en el ejemplo [cpp.sh/4ujq](http://cpp.sh/4ujq), pero si fuera como el caso del autor de la pregunta entonces no.

Answer (score 3):

Todos los arrays tienen al final un caracter nulo, lo cual debes respetar, y recuerda que todos los arrays (o arreglos como prefieras llamarles) empiezan en 0, asi que un array de 100 puedes llenar 99 espacio del 0 al 98 pero no el 99

Como experiencia personal te sugiero que escribas condiciones con for o if, provocando que salte automaticamente si va a llegar al limite

Comment: "*Todos los arrays tienen al final un caracter nulo*" esto es un pequeño error. Los arrays (o arreglos) no tienen ningún caracter nulo, son las cadenas de caracteres, que son un tipo de array. Así pues las cadenas de caracteres finalizan con un caracter nulo, los array no.

Comment: gracias por la correcion amigo, pense que aplicaba para todos, bueno quisiera tener profesores que explique todo hasta al minimo detalle y no solo te hagan hacer ejercicios, salu2

Comment: Los literales de texto (cadenas de caracteres) tienen un tratamiento especial en muchos lenguajes de programación, en el caso de C y de C++ este tratamiento especial implica el añadir una marca de final de caena (`'\0'`) en otros lenguajes como Java o C# el objeto String es un tipo nativo (no un objeto de librería) y éste almacena internamente el tamaño de la cadena.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Agrego un detalle. En C también almacena el tamaño en la RAM, se puede hacer trampa y ver una posición negativa de la cadena y transformar esos datos binarios en uno entero decimal. Aunque eso más bien depende del compilador más que el propio lenguaje.

Comment: @ArtEze eso es muy interesante ¿hay documentación oficial al respecto o es una característica de ciertos compiladores?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster No sé si hay documentación, es un descubrimiento personal mientras yo intentaba programar la función longitud, cuando me lo pidieron como ejercicio en la universidad.

Comment: @ArtEze podría ser un caso de "*small string optimization*", debería estar documentado en algún sitio; vale la pena investigarlo. Pero sin duda no es estándar; ni el estándar de C ni el de C++ requieren que un literal de texto contenga su longitud a diferencia del builtin String de C# o Java.